# The best way to replace multiple if-statementes with a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I have a multiple condition:

```
if you == 1 or you == 2:
    one.put(argument)
elif you == 3:
    return None
elif you == 4:
    two.put(argument)
elif you == 5:
    three.put(argument)
elif you == 6:
    four.put(argument)
elif you == 7:
    five.put(argument)
elif you == 8:
    six.put(argument)
elif you == 9:
    seven.put(argument)
elif you == 10:
    eight.put(argument)
elif you == 11:
    nine.put(argument)
elif you == 12:
    ten.put(argument)
```

I want to change it to use a dictionary, but I get exceptions in:

```
if you == 1 or you == 2:
    one.put(argument)
elif you == 3:
    return None
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You should ask that on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What  exceptions?

Comment: maybe, but i am studying. i am not yet a professional developer

Comment: @DeepSpace  from first to fourth lines. not the same, that we use after fourth line

Comment: So I wrote a blog about using python dictionaries instead of if-else statements in the past. You can read about it [here](https://kirankoduru.github.io/python/python-dict-functions.html)

Comment: You only have one `return` statement. What do you return otherwise, or is it `None` by default as well?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to CodeReviw.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the varying part of your expression in a dictionary.
I put 3 in there as well, just for completeness, and possible later use.

```
put_dict = {
    1: one, 2: one,
    3: None
    4: two,  5: three,
    6: four, 7: five,
    8: six,  9: seven,
    10: eight, 11: nine,
    12: ten
}

if you == 3:
    return None
else:
    put_dict[you].put(argument)
```

Answer (score 6):

This will work:

```
actions = {1: one.put,
           2: one.put,
           3: None,
           4: two.put,
           # ....
           }

action = actions.get(you)
if callable(action):  # guards against non existing "you"'s or if you == 3
    action(argument)

# can also do this:
# if action is not None:
    # action(argument)

# or that..
# try:
#     action(argument)
# except TypeError:  # if action is None we'll get an exception, NoneType isn't callable
#    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a sink for the values you don't want:

```
class Sink:
    @staticmethod
    def put(object):
        pass

put_dict = {
    1: one, 2: one,
    3: Sink,
    4: two,  5: three,
    6: four, 7: five,
    8: six,  9: seven,
    10: eight, 11: nine,
    12: ten}

def function(you, argument)
    put_dict[you].put(argument)
```